# Change ipython notebook font type

Tags: ipython

I want to change the font type in my ipython notebook to consolas font type. I first generated a profile using

`ipython profile create`

But, I am not clear on the syntax to specify the font type in this config file.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
-Uma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ipython notebook (the web interface to ipython) uses standard html/css to define the appearance.  If you make changes to these files, it will alter the appearance of your ipython notebook.

Locate your ipython egg distribution.  I installed mine using easy_install, so my path looks like this:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.12.1-py2.6.egg/IPython/frontend/html/notebook/static/css
```

Basically you just want to find the ipython install location, then go to the path shown above.  Update your css, restart your ipython server, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Option 2: change the monospace font preference in your browser.