# Increasing the font size for just certain cells/one notebook in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to increase the font size and add boldness to my outputted text in Jupyter notebook. However, I just want to change the settings for that particular notebook or that particular cell. (both solutions are welcomed)

I see most threads showing how to configure the .css files which I'm assuming is a global change?

[How to change font in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386359/how-to-change-font-in-ipython-notebook)

However I want cell by cell control or just that particular notebook.

As an example output of one my cells is the following:

`Killing C.I.A. Informants, China Crippled U.S. Spying
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/20/world/asia/china-cia-spies-espionage.html`

I would like to make the first sentence(the title) bold.

Thank you.

EDIT:
   Trying to utilize the markdown method within this loop.

```
for i in today_links:
    if i[0] == '':
        del (i)
    else:
        Markdown('**{}**  \n{}'.format(i[0], i[1]))
```

today_links is a list of tuples

```
[('Killing C.I.A. Informants, China Crippled U.S. Spying',
  'https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/20/world/asia/china-cia-spies-espionage.html'),
 ('How Rollbacks at Pruitt’s E.P.A. Are a Boon to Oil and Gas',
  'https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/20/business/energy-environment/devon-energy.html'),
```

Not sure why it's not working within the loop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you are talking about output cells from your code... obviously you can use markdown cells and control the formatting for documentation cells.

Assuming two variables:

```
title = "Killing C.I.A. Informants, China Crippled U.S. Spying"
url = "https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/20/world/asia/china-cia-spies-espionage.html"
```

For output cells from code you can do a similar thing and use the `IPython.display.Markdown`, e.g.:

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
Markdown('<strong>{}</strong><br/>{}'.format(title, url))
```

Output:

> **Killing C.I.A. Informants, China Crippled U.S. Spying**
> https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/20/world/asia/china-cia-spies-espionage.html

If you want to do it in the middle of a loop you need to explicitly call `display()`, e.g.:

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
for i in today_links:
    display(Markdown('**{}**  \n{}'.format(i[0], i[1])))
```

Output:

> **Killing C.I.A. Informants, China Crippled U.S. Spying**
> https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/20/world/asia/china-cia-spies-espionage.html
>
> **How Rollbacks at Pruitt’s E.P.A. Are a Boon to Oil and Gas**
> https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/20/business/energy-environment/devon-energy.html

Alternatively you can use `IPython.display.HTML`:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
HTML('<strong>{}</strong><br/>{}'.format(title, url))
```

Output:

> **Killing C.I.A. Informants, China Crippled U.S. Spying**
> https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/20/world/asia/china-cia-spies-espionage.html

You can also embed variables into a Markdown cell directly *(note: there are 2 spaces at the end of `**{{title}}**` line to force a new line)*:

Markdown Cell

```
**{{title}}**  
{{url}}
```

Output:

> **Killing C.I.A. Informants, China Crippled U.S. Spying**
> https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/20/world/asia/china-cia-spies-espionage.html

Comment: Thank you. Going to play around with this a bit.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing the markdown method (1st option) within a for loop. I  will update the OP with the loop code.

Comment: If you want it in the middle of a loop you just need to `display()` (like `print()`). Updated answer!

Comment: Works great.  I just need to adjust the font size now.  For completeness to the question, can you please also include how to adjust the font size using markdown. Thank you so much.

Comment: Markdown doesn't provide you that level of control, if you need that level of control then you will need to go to `HTML()`. In Markdown you do have `headers` using `#`, e.g. `# H1`, `## H2`, ... `###### H6`, you may be able to use one of those if it gives you the right output, e.g. `Markdown('#### {}\n{}'.format(i[0], i[1]))`

Comment: Thanks this helps.

Comment: The font size for `HTML()` could be controlled by putting  e.g.`<font size="6">` and `</font>` at either side of the text.