# How to increase the Jupyter Notebook output size

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Specifically I need a higher resolution of the output in the jupyter notebook for reporting in my project file .For example it would be helpful if i can get higher Dimension size of `pandas.info()` for instance. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPyZC.jpg). The Output in the current dimensions is blurred after converting it into pdf from word document

Comment: "The Output in the curent dimensions is blurred after converting it into pdf from word document" Huh? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change font in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386359/how-to-change-font-in-ipython-notebook)