# How can I increase the size of Jupyter notebook cells and text?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to increase the size of my cells and text to increase readability, I already tried this solution: [How do I increase the cell width of the Jupyter/ipython notebook in my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser).

However that just made the cells wider and not bigger, so all text stays the same small size.

[Screenshot of Jupyter notebook now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBHFS.png)

[What I want Jupyter notebook to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wczQ.png)

Comment: This isn't a python issue it's a browser issue. `Ctrl+` will probably fix it.

Comment: @TBurgis Okay thanks. Will just use ctrl+ each time, hoped there would be a permanent fix.

Answer (score -4):

This isn't related to Python.
I'm guessing your monitor is pretty big.
Just try zooming in your view for this particular page.

On Chrome this is Cmd and +

Comment: Thanks, I hoped there would be a permanent fix will use this instead.

Comment: You can change the [font jupyter uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386359/how-to-change-font-in-ipython-notebook) but this looks like the font size has been changed in the browser. If you `Ctrl+` until the text is a good size and then open a new notebook what is the font size like in that?