# Jupyter Notebook output inconsistent across browsers

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to draw a table on Jupyter Notebook, but the outputs are not consistent across browser. For instance, the spacing works well in Chrome, but not in firefox. Also I can't use pandas Dataframe's `display()` due to some limitations and have to draw it manually. Any ideas on how to make it print properly across browsers?

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Relevant code:

```
def print_report(self, df):
    print("{0: <45}{1: <70}{2: <8}".format("Control ID", "Control Description", "Status"))
    self.line()
    for indx, x in df.iterrows():
        print("{0: <45}{1: <70}{2: <8}".format(x["ControlName"], x["ControlDescription"], x["Result"]))
    self.line()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between browsers is probably because they have different default monospace font settings.

But if you're looking to produce the exact same styling across browsers, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27031060/7315159) about adding custom CSS to ipython notebooks may be what you're looking for.

Comment: You are a life saver! I was wondering why it looked so different between browsers and changed the default font but didn't think about looking for the specific monospace setting.
Obviously code is going to use monospace duh! Thank you so much.